# Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5 BAD EIP Error

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, rhel

I have installed red hat enterpirse linux 5 but after finishing installation i got kernel panic error with BAD EIP error and I also found that there are no files in /sys and /proc directories.can any one help me and also I cannot boot this red hat from already existing grub version 2 though after adding its entry in grub.cfg file.can nay one help me?

Comment: the already existing grub is of ubuntu 10

Comment: i have tried the same installation with different installation medias and on two different machines it has given me same problem on both machines